# Predicate looking for ID that doesn't exist?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a method like so:

```
func syncSectors(sectors: [SectorsModel]){

    BackgroundContext.performAndWait {
        //Fetch results from the database
        let matchingSectorRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Sectors")
        //Delete Sector ids
        let deleteSectorIds = sectors.map { $0.ID }.compactMap { $0 }

        matchingSectorRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: " !(ANY sector_id IN %@) AND (sector_id != nil)", argumentArray: [deleteSectorIds])


        let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest.init(fetchRequest: matchingSectorRequest)
        batchDeleteRequest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs

        // Execute the request to do batch delete and merge the changes to viewContext, which triggers the UI update
        do {
            let batchDeleteResult: NSBatchDeleteResult = try BackgroundContext.execute(batchDeleteRequest) as! NSBatchDeleteResult

            if let deletedObjectIDs = batchDeleteResult.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] {
                NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: [NSDeletedObjectsKey: deletedObjectIDs], into: [Context])
            }

        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)\nCould not batch delete existing records.")
            return
        }
        //******************** End of Delete Sectors *****************************

        // Insert new SubSectors
        for sector in sectors where !sector.exists {
            _ =  saveSectors(sectors: sectors)
        }

        do {
            // Save all changes on background context
            try BackgroundContext.save()

            Context.performAndWait {
                do {
                    // Saves the data from the background to the main context
                    try Context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Failure to save context: \(error)")
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)\nCould not save new records.")

            BackgroundContext.rollback()

            return
        }

        //******************** End of Insert new Sectors *****************************

        //Update Sectors
        for sector in sectors where !sector.ID.isNilOrEmpty{

            let batchUpdateRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest.init(entityName: "Sectors")
            batchUpdateRequest.resultType = .updatedObjectIDsResultType
            batchUpdateRequest.predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "sector_id == %@", sector.ID)

            //Perform the inital update
            batchUpdateRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["sector_id" :sector.ID, "SECTOR_NAME" : sector.SECTOR_NAME]

            // Execute the request to do batch update and merge the changes to viewContext, which triggers the UI update
            do {
                let batchUpdateResult: NSBatchUpdateResult = try BackgroundContext.execute(batchUpdateRequest) as! NSBatchUpdateResult

                if let UpdatedObjectIDs = batchUpdateResult.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] {
                    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: [NSUpdatedObjectsKey: UpdatedObjectIDs],
                                                        into: [Context])
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error: \(error)\nCould not batch update existing records.")
                return
            }
            //******************** End of Update Sectors *****************************


        }
    }

}
```

My app crashes when I reach this point:

if let deletedObjectIDs = batchDeleteResult.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] {
                    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: [NSDeletedObjectsKey: deletedObjectIDs], into: [Context])
                }

the IDs that I have in my Array are as follows:

Printing description of deleteSectorIds:
▿ 24 elements
  - 0 : "8"
  - 1 : "9"
  - 2 : "11"
  - 3 : "12"
  - 4 : "13"
  - 5 : "14"
  - 6 : "15"
  - 7 : "16"
  - 8 : "17"
  - 9 : "18"
  - 10 : "19"
  - 11 : "20"
  - 12 : "21"
  - 13 : "22"
  - 14 : "23"
  - 15 : "24"
  - 16 : "25"
  - 17 : "27"
  - 18 : "28"
  - 19 : "29"
  - 20 : "30"
  - 21 : "31"
  - 22 : "32"
  - 23 : "33"

And I cant seem to figure out why I am getting this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath ID not found in entity '

when I clearly do not have an ID with the value 7 in my array?

Anyone who can break it down for me whats really going on?

My model is as follows:

import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

enum SectorsModelEnum: String {

```
case SECTOR_NAME = "SECTOR_NAME"
case ID = "ID"
case SECTOR = "SECTOR"
```

}

struct SectorsModel: Mappable {

```
var SECTOR_NAME: String!
var ID: String!
var SECTOR: [SubSectorsModel]!

init?(map: Map) {

}

init(SECTOR_NAME: String, ID: String, SECTOR: [SubSectorsModel] ) {

    self.SECTOR_NAME = SECTOR_NAME
    self.ID = ID
    self.SECTOR = SECTOR

}

init() {
    self.SECTOR = []
    self.SECTOR_NAME = ""
    self.ID = ""
}

mutating func mapping(map: Map) {

    SECTOR_NAME <- map[SectorsModelEnum.SECTOR_NAME.rawValue]
    ID <- map[SectorsModelEnum.ID.rawValue]
    SECTOR <- map[SectorsModelEnum.SECTOR.rawValue]

}

var exists: Bool {
    let fetchRequest = Sectors.sectorsFetchRequest()
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ID == %@", ID )
    var sectors: [Sectors] = []
    do {
        sectors = try Context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    } catch {
        print("Could not fetch data \(error)")
    }
    return sectors.first != nil ? true : false
}
```

}

Comment: why do you have sector_id and ID. Can you show the Sector model

Comment: My sector model is like this: import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

enum SectorsModelEnum: String {
    
    
    case SECTOR_NAME = "SECTOR_NAME"
    case ID = "ID"
    case SECTOR = "SECTOR"
}


struct SectorsModel: Mappable {
    
   
    var SECTOR_NAME: String!
    var ID: String!
    var SECTOR: [SubSectorsModel]!
}

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you add that to the question so it's easier to read? how is the core data entity defined/setup?